# Java: insert accented characters in mysql

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, non-ascii-characters

If I have this query from java:

```
String query="insert into user (..., name, ...) values (..., 'à', ...)";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Spinning?user=root");
PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(query);
prest.executeUpdate();
```

In the db I will have a strange character: a diamond with a question mark inside.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: It'll be down to the character-set that you're using, though it's hard to say exactly where if hard-coded try looking at the class file first

Comment: @BobFlannigon I can't understand where I have to look....In the class file?

Comment: What's the CREATE statement used to create the table? The name column needs to have proper encoding (preferably unicode) to support all accented characters

Comment: I edit the question with all the code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your connection url to the following:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/Spinning?user=root&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify the character set you are using in MySQL DB. You can try "`SHOW CREATE TABLE xxxx`" to print the table DDL with charset being used.
2. Verify the character set you are using in JDBC driver. If using MySQL `ConnectorJ,` you can set charset in the JDBC url.